# How to initialize manually next.js app (for testing purpose)?

Tags: testing, next.js

I try to test my web services, hosted in my Next.js app and I have an error with not found Next.js configuration.

My web service are regular one, stored in the `pages/api` directory.
My API test fetches a constant `ATTACKS_ENDPOINT` thanks to this file:

*/pages/api/**tests**/api.spec.js*

```
import { ATTACKS_ENDPOINT } from "../config"

...

describe("endpoints", () => {
   beforeAll(buildOptionsFetch)

   it("should return all attacks for attacks endpoint", async () => {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL + ATTACKS_ENDPOINT, headers)
```

*config.js*

```
import getConfig from "next/config"

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()

export const API_URL = publicRuntimeConfig.API_URL
```

My next.config.js is present and is used properly by the app when started.

When the test is run, this error is thrown

```
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property `publicRuntimeConfig` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

  1 | import getConfig from "next/config"
  2 | 
> 3 | const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()
```

I looked for solutions and I found this [issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/8286#issuecomment-540469132) which talks about _manually initialise__ next app.

How to do that, given that I don't test React component but API web service ?

Comment: I believe what you are looking to do is to mock the next obkect. What testing library do you use? Perhaps I can explain further with that testing framework

Comment: I use Jest for testing purpose

Comment: jest with super test to test the routes under pages

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by creating a `jest.setup.js` file and adding this line of code

First add jest.setup.js to jest.config.js file

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  // Your config
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
};
```

AND then

```
// jest.setup.js

jest.mock('next/config', () => () => ({
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    YOUR_PUBLIC_VARIABLE: 'value-of-env'  // Change this line and copy your env
  }
}))
```

OR

```
// jest.setup.js
import { setConfig } from 'next/config'
import config from './next.config'

// Make sure you can use "publicRuntimeConfig" within tests.
setConfig(config)
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the third solution and it went very well 

Answer (score 1):

The problem I faced with testing with Jest was that next was not being initialized as expected. My solution was to mock the next module... You can try this:

```js
/** @jest-environment node */
jest.mock('next');

import next from 'next';

next.mockReturnValue({
    prepare: () => Promise.resolve(),
    getRequestHandler: () => (req, res) => res.status(200),
    getConfig: () => ({
        publicRuntimeConfig: {} /* This is where you import the mock values */
    })
});
```

Read about manual mocks here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to:

1. Create a `jest.setup.js` file and

```js
setConfig({
    ...config,
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        BASE_PATH: '/',
        SOME_KEY: 'your_value',
    },
    serverRuntimeConfig: {
        YOUR_KEY: 'your_value',
    },
});
```

2. Then add this in your `jest.config.js` file:

```js
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
```